# Converting logic of DateTime.FromBinary method in TSQL query

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime

I have a table that contain column with `VARBINARY(MAX)` data type. That column represents different values for different types in my c# DB layer class. It can be: `int`, `string` and `datetime`. Now I need to convert that one column into three by it's type. So values with `int` type go to new column `ObjectIntValue` and so on for every new column.

But I have a problems with transmitting data to `datetime` column, because the old column contains `datetime` value as a `long` received from C# `DateTime.ToBinary` method while data saving.

I should make that in TSQL and can't using .NET for convert that value in new column. Have you any ideas?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can you use the CLR integration ?

Comment: What version of sql server, 2005 onwards you can use .net in sql server. It can be a bit slow but for a one off job like this it will be okay.

Comment: MSSQL Version is 2008 R2 but how can I use .NET class methods? For example DateTime.FromBinary() ?

Comment: As a matter of fact I should make this in tSQL quary becouse in our project have a update sql script file for DB version control. That file is a litle bit specific and we can't use TSLQ operators like GO in it. So I think it will be difficult to enable CLR integration in that script.

Answer (score 0):

Using CLR in T_SQl

Basically you use Create Assembly to register the dll with your function(s) in it,
Then create a user defined function to call it, then you can use it.
There's several rules depending on what you want to do, but as basically you only want DateTime.FromBinary(), shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Never done it myself, but these guys seem to know what they are talking about

[CLR in TSQL tutorial](http://www.vistadb.net/tutorials/clr-procs.aspx)

This is a one off convert right? Your response to @schglurps is a bit of a concern.

If I get you there would have to be break in your update script, ie the one you have woukld work up to when you implement this chnage, then you's have a one off procedure for this manouevre, then  you would be updating from a new version.

If you want to validate it, just check for the existnec or non-existance of the new columns.

Other option would be to write a wee application that filled in the new columns from the old one and invoke it. Ugh...

If this isn't one off and you want to keep and maintain the old column, then you have problems.

Comment: I've found solution [here](http://extendeddotnet.blogspot.com/2011/10/convert-net-datetimeticks-to-t-sql.html)

Comment: Might work after some twidling But DateTime.ToBinary is Kind as well as ticks.

Comment: In function body just after begining I've added: ` set @Ticks = @Ticks&cast(4611686018427387903 as bigint);` and everythings is became fine.