# Converting binary bigint from VB.NET to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, binary

I have a bigint field in SQL Server called FirstRegistered. To populate this, a VB.NET program runs the following line:

```
dr.FirstRegistered = Date.Today.ToBinary
```

This writes a value (such as -8586003237024012017) and when using FromBinary in VB.NET, this translates as 28/09/2020 09:53:03

However, I cannot seem to work out how to do the equivalent of FromBinary in SQL Server. I have tried using:

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        SWITCHOFFSET(
            CAST(
                dateadd(
                    ms,
                    convert( bigint, [FirstRegistered] ) / 10000,
                    convert( datetime, '1/1/1970 00:00:00' )
                )
                AS DATETIMEOFFSET
            ),
            DATENAME( TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() )
        ) AS DATETIME
    )
```

However, this results in an arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: Why are you storing it as a binary value in the first place if you want to use it as a date? Why not just store it as a date?

Comment: Primarily to ease the need of working out a consistent date format from multiple cultures I believe. I inherited the structure so can't be certain but my understanding is that to avoid complications with different cultures writing different date formats, storing the value as a bigint was considered the best way around it.

Comment: *"to ease the need of working out a consistent date format from multiple cultures"*. There is no such need. Format is only relevant when storing text. If you use a dedicated data type, e.g. `datetime` or `datetime2`, then the value is stored as a binary date anyway, so there is no cultural format consideration. When you need to use a literal value in SQL code, you just use 'yyyy-MM-dd' format every time and there's never an issue. You use the `DateTime` data type in VB and there's no format issue there either. That is a solution to a problem that doesn't exist but it's created a problem.

Comment: As for why you're getting the error, `CONVERT( bigint, 0x88D8638BE8D4690F ) / 10000` returns `-858600323702401`, still far too small for an `int` (which can't hold a value lower than -2,147,483,648).

Comment: Even so, the difference in milliseconds between `1970-01-01` and `2020-09-28T09:53:03` is `1601286783000`; a completely different number.

Comment: So it's all a bit odd. If I do the following in VB.NET - CDate("28/09/2020 09:53:03").ToBinary, I get 637368835830000000. If I do Date.Today.ToBinary (let's pretend the date is the one in the string here), I get -8586003237024012017 which if you then use CDate.FromBinary(CLng(-8586003237024012017)), you get 28/09/2020 09:53:03.

Comment: Since the value of `FirstRegistered` only has meaning in a .Net CLR environment, it may make sense to enable [SQL Server Common Language Runtime Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-common-language-runtime-integration) and expose  'DateTime.FromBinary' via a SQL UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TnTinMn and all others who looked at this. That put me on the right trail - I found the answer here ([Converting logic of DateTime.FromBinary method in TSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464504/converting-logic-of-datetime-frombinary-method-in-tsql-query)) and here (http://extendeddotnet.blogspot.com/2011/10/convert-net-datetimeticks-to-t-sql.html) which was indeed to write a function and use that to convert in SQL Server (and make the Ticks amendment).

I could then run:

```
SELECT dbo.NetFxUtcTicksToDateTime(-8586003237024012017) AS TimeIWant
```

To convert successfully to 2020-09-28 09:53:03:077. Thanks again to all who helped and for the extra advice from John which I will definitely look to use in the future.